# Cordova file input not working on android 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, file-io, android-4.4-kitkat

I wanted to upload a file with input type="file" it works every where except on Android 4.4 . 
No action when taping on the file input ! 
I'm using cordova 3.5.0 . 
I searched around but didn't find a real working answer . 
I need it very much in my project especially for uploading .pdf files . 
Thank you in advance !